# Is it possible to use ENUM value as a #key in @Cacheable annotation?

Tags: java, spring, caching, protocol-buffers, spring-cache

I would like to do something like this:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "cahcedDataCOllection", cacheManager = "cacheManagerInMemory", key="#request.enum.value")
public MyProto.GetSomethingResponse getSomething(MyProto.GetSomethingRequest request) {
       ...
}
```

Thats perfectly works with any object property, but I am facing an issue when I use enum.

**Maybe this is important:**

The request/response objects are protobuf generated java code.

Comment: `cahcedDataCOllection` ?

Comment: and the actual issue is?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy cacheNames = "cahcedDataCOllection" it does not matter, its just a name of a stored map in cacheManager. They should match in both.

Comment: @M.Deinum actual issue is that it fails on a data type error when requesting data. Cannot provide an actual error message, because its on a working laptop, cannot access now. But google that does not giving any help

Comment: Please add the error/stacktrace you get as there is far too little information to help answering this question.